# JsonSerializer deserialize to anonymous type

Tags: c#

How do I deserialize a JSON to an anonymous type?

I have this working code that's:

- defining a JSON with Foo and Bar fields
- defining a model as anonymous type with Foo property
- deserializing the JSON using the generic method

```cs
    [Fact]
    public void Test1()
    {
        const string json = """
        {
            "Foo": "a",
            "Bar": "b"
        }
        """;

        var model = new
        {
            Foo = default(string),
        };

        var deserialized = Deserialize(json, model);

        var a = deserialized.Foo;

        a.Should().Be("a");
    }

    private T Deserialize<T>(string json, T model) => JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(json) ?? model;
```

I would like to do the same without the generic Deserialize method. Below the code:

```cs
    [Fact]
    public void Test2()
    {
        const string json = """
        {
            "Foo": "a",
            "Bar": "b"
        }
        """;

        var model = new
        {
            Foo = default(string),
        };

        var deserialized = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<??????>(json);
        string a = deserialized.Foo;

        a.Should().Be("a");
    }
```

Not sure what to put instead of the `??????`. Ideally I'd like to specify something like `typeof(model)` or `model.GetType()`, but those are not accepted by the compiler

Comment: If that is via NewtonSoft then `model = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(json, model);` should do.

Comment: I don't think there is a real solution to this. Generics are a compile time thing anonymous types is a more runtime thing. That does not fit well. So all solutions presented actually just try to circumvent this somehow but aren't better then you initial solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ExpandoObject`.

```
var deserialized = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<ExpandoObject>(json);
string a = deserialized.Foo.ToString();
...
```

If you want you can also create extension method like below:

```
public static dynamic? DeserializeAsDynamic(this string json)
{
    var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExpandoObject>(json);
    return result;
}
```

Sample usage:

```
dynamic obj = json.DeserializeAsDynamic();
```

Comment: I tried what you suggested with `ExpandoObject` and it does not compile. However, if we specify the type as dynamic and use the `ToString()` it does:

        ```dynamic deserialized = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<ExpandoObject>(json);
        string a = deserialized.Foo.ToString();```

Comment: Yes, you're right, I missed that part. Since the compiler cannot understand the type of properties when you return dynamic, it shows them as dynamic as well. You will need to cast or you have to use ToString.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that this will suit your actual use case, but for current one you can try using `Dictionary`:

```cs
var deserialized = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, string>>(json);
string a = deserialized["Foo"];
```

Or just introduce the class, with [`record`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/record)s (C# 9) and [`file`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/file) keyword (C# 11) it should extremely simple and effortless:

```cs
file record RecordForTest1(string Foo, string Bar);

[Fact]
public void Test1()
{
    // ...
    var deserialized = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<RecordForTest1>(json);
}
```

Comment: dynamic doesn't work, I get this exception ```Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException
'System.Text.Json.JsonElement' does not contain a definition for 'Foo'```

Comment: @Jorgoth yes, this should have worked with Newtonsoft Json...  Updated post, but for your concrete question - there is no other workaround other then yours  or some reflection.